# I can't create a new card with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Problem:** 
I want to write a program that adds a new card when the button is pressed. I can connect and change states, but no new cards. (There is no problem that the value in the state is constant. The important thing is the formation of the new card).

There are two different components above. When the button is pressed (same state), I want a new card to be created. But I couldn't write the code.

---

**card.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import CardStyle from '../cardStyle/cardStyle';

class Card extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      imageUrl: null,
      fullName: null,
      job: null
    };
  }

  clickEvent = () => {
    this.setState({
      fullName: 'Furkan',
      job: 'Software engineer'
    });
  }

  render() {
    let {isLoading, imageUrl, fullName, job} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <CardStyle 
              isLoading={isLoading}
              imageUrl = {imageUrl}
              fullName = {fullName}
              job = {job}
              clicked = {this.clickEvent}
              />
        <button onClick={this.clickEvent}>ADD PERSON</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Card;
```

---

**cardStyle.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import classes from "./cardStyle.css";
import Wrap from "../../Wrap/Wrap";

class CardStyle extends Component {
  state = {
    image: null,
    fullName: null,
    job: null
  };

  createCard = () => {
    return(
      <div className={classes.Card}>      
        <div className={classes.Image}>{this.props.imageUrl}</div>
        <div className={classes.Title}>{this.props.fullName}</div>
        <div className={classes.Job}>{this.props.job}</div>
      </div>
    )
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Wrap>
        {this.createCard()}
      </Wrap>
    ) 
  }
}

export default CardStyle;
```

Comment: When you say "a new card", what exactly do you mean?  Currently you have a single Card object.  Clicking your button sets a couple of values used to render that object.  If you want to have multiple cards then presumably somewhere you'd have an array.  Where do you track that?  Semantically I wouldn't expect a component called `Card` to be a collection of cards.  I'd expect it to be a card.  And the component which contains it would maintain the collection, as well as the functionality to modify that collection.

Comment: Look into React List Components. A good way to do this is CardList component that renders an array of Card components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a new card every time you click your button, you should create cards array which maps every new card to a component. This way you will get a new card with every click instead of modifying the old card.

```
import React from 'react'
import CardStyle from '../cardStyle/cardStyle';

class Card extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cards: [
        {
          isLoading: true,
          imageUrl: null,
          fullName: null,
          job: null
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  clickEvent = () => {
    const cards = [
      ...this.state.cards,
      {
        fullName: 'Furkan',
        job: 'Software engineer'
      }
    ]; // This will create a new array from the old one with a new additional value
    this.setState({ cards });
  }

  render() {
    const { cards } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {cards.map((card, index) => (
            <CardStyle 
              key={index}
              isLoading={card.isLoading}
              imageUrl = {card.imageUrl}
              fullName = {card.fullName}
              job = {card.job}
              />
        )}

        <button onClick={this.clickEvent}>ADD PERSON</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Card;
```

Comment: The first card is a blank card. How can I prevent this?

Comment: You can remove the first card by simply leaving `this.state = { cards: [] };`. Or is the first card visibility before the click is a necessity to you?

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling `clickEvent` method, you do not adding another value to the `state`, but you're overwrite existing: `imgUrl` and `fullName`.

You have to create array of cards, and display them by `map` method inside `return`.

If first card is blank for now, you can start from empty array in state `cards: []`, and display `CardStyle` component only if `this.state.cards.length > 0`.